# problems generating certificate from RSA public key with for java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509, public-key

Im making the methods for signature and verification and need to make the keys that correspond with eachother from the keystore. The methods im using for signature and verification gets the keys from my JCEKS keystore and will use them to sign and verify the signature.

I tried the signature/verification methods with regular KeyPair generation and it seems to work by returning true on verify, but when i try with key's from the keystore it returns false.

Here is a method i tried earlier that would return false:

```
    public Certificate[] generateCertificateChain() throws IOException, CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        Resource certRes = resourceLoader.getResource("file:cert.pem");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(certRes.getInputStream());
        Certificate[] certificateChain = {cert};

        return certificateChain;
    }
```

```
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(publicKeyData.getModulusInteger(), publicKeyData.getPublicExponentInteger());
        PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);

        keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, publicKey.getEncoded(), generateCertificateChain());
        OutputStream writeStream = new FileOutputStream(keyStorePath);
        keyStore.store(writeStream, keyStorePassword);
```

I may be generating and storing my certificate wrong. Here is the method im trying now without using the two above: Here i get error message: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length

```
    @Override
    public void storePublicKey(String alias, RsaPublicKeyData publicKeyData)
            throws CertificateException,
            IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException,
            KeyStoreException {

        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(publicKeyData.getModulusInteger(), publicKeyData.getPublicExponentInteger());
        PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);

        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(publicKey.getEncoded()));
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        OutputStream writeStream = new FileOutputStream(keyStorePath);
        keyStore.store(writeStream, keyStorePassword);

    }
```

Comment: Your "now trying" third block is wrong and fails because a publickey is not a certificate. A certificate _contains_ a publickey, and uninformed people think that is its only purpose, but in fact it also contains many other things and its structure is very different. It's not clear to me what you actually want to accomplish so I can't comment on the rest.